# How to make site not change anything when window is resized?

Tags: html, css, button, resize, responsive

I'm trying to make it so that when I user resizes there window it wont move anything on the page, and it wont resize anything. But I still wont the site to look the same on different screen sizes. Because right now the website moves my image and my buttons. The buttons also change size.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

img {
    margin-top: 230px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.home {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 500px;
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 750px;
}

.projects {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 1000px;
}

.contact {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 26px;
    width: 10%;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 1250px;
}

.home:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}

.about:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}

.projects:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}

.contact:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Play" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <canvas class='connecting-dots'></canvas>
    
    <h3>Title</h3>
    
    <a href="#"><div class = "home">Home</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class = "about">About</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class = "projects">Projects</div></a>
    <a href="#"><div class = "contact">Contact</div></a>
    
    <img src="astronaut.png">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why everything is position absolute ?

Comment: Idk, I'm kinda new to web development.

Comment: ok understand. so you want a header menu with title ? but why those canvas and the img ?

Comment: The canvas is using JavaScript to create floating particles, but I didn't include the JavaScript. I don't think that's causing the problem.

Comment: problem is your html structure and css position , margin-left etc.

Comment: How should I fix my css position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set min-width: and min-height: on your elements. That will prevent them from getting any smaller and then you can do max-width and max-height to prevent them from growing. Also, change it from width:10%; to a solid/absolute number. This is saying 10% of whatever screen it is displayed on.

http://codepen.io/Squeakasaur/pen/OpwWqG

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box; }

#wrapper {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ccc;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0; 
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 70px;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

img {
    margin-top: 230px;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.home {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 500px;
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 60px;
      width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 750px;
}

.projects {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
        min-width: ;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 60px;
      width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 26px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 1000px;
}

.contact {
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
    line-height: 60px;
    font-size: 26px;
       width: 150px;
    height: 60px;
    margin-top: 180px;
    margin-left: 1250px;
}

.home:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}

.about:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}

.projects:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}

.contact:hover{
    border-color: #0091FF;
    color: #0091FF;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the only problem I am having is that I would like to have the min-width set to 100% of the page. But when I set it to 100% it just ends up resizing the page.

Comment: Set your elements to have a min and max and not to 100%. Or do this:    width: 150px; Right now you have everything set to width: 10%; when a screen size changes it is saying 10% of the current screen. If you set a solid width you wont have the issue.

Comment: I want the website to look the same on other screen sizes. If I set everything to specific sizes instead of percentages, wouldn't it look too big or too small on other screens?

Comment: Different resolution is going to look different but the width of the item wont change. Right now as you shrink your website your text starts to move outside your divs.

Comment: Ok, I set the width for all the buttons to 200px. That fixed the buttons from moving, but the next issue is that the image still moves.

Comment: where are you trying to keep the image?

Comment: In the center of the screen

Comment: Are you trying to make it a background image?

Comment: I figured it out actually. But I have one last question, how can I make my buttons perfectly centered? I want the center of the screen to be directly in between the two middle buttons.

Comment: Add display: inline-block; and  margin: auto; to each button